# Trouble verifying incorrect input in program

Tags: java, validation

I've written an infix to postfix calculator. 
It works fine as long as the infix equations are valid, but I can't figure out how to handle invalid equations.

My program reads infix equations from a text file separated by line breaks. It prints the results of the converted postfix problems into a new text file. I am trying to have it so that if one equation is invalid, instead of breaking the program it simply prints "Invalid" on the output page. I'm not sure what to do!

My idea was to create a case in the list of switches that mentioned "all other chars" somehow, since any char that isn't an operator or operand, but I can't get that to work at all, and am suspicious it's impossible.

```
public class ExpressionTools extends ConsoleCalculator {
//for infix to postfix
static Stack s;
static String in;
private String out = "";

/**
 * expression tools
 * @param input
 */
public ExpressionTools(String input) {
    in = input; // input = inputed string
    s = new Stack<Character>(); // stack = stack of chars
}

/**
 * Determines string precedence
 * @throws PostFixException
 * @throws IOException
 */
public String precedence() throws PostFixException, IOException {
    // check for string precedence
    // for each character in the given string
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
        char cha = in.charAt(i);
        switch (cha) {
        // if + or -
        case '+':
        case '-':
            operator(cha, 1);
            break;
        // First level of precedence
        // if * or /
        case '*':
        case '/':
            operator(cha, 2); // pop
            break;
        // second level of precedence
        case '(':
            s.push(cha); // if open paren, add to stack
            break;
        case ')':
            parentheses(cha); // pop operators
            break;
        default: 
            out = out + cha;
            break;// write to output string
        }
    }

    // while stack is not empty, add character to output
    while (!s.isEmpty()) {
        out = out + s.pop();
    }
    postfix.add(out);
    return out; // returns postfix expression
}   

/**
 * sets precedence of operators
 * 
 * @param oper
 * @param precedence1
 * @throws PostFixException
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public void operator(char oper, int precedence1) throws PostFixException, IOException {
    // while the stack is not empty
    // check precedence of operators
    while (!s.isEmpty()) {
        char head = (char) s.pop();
        if (head == '(') { // if bracket, push character
            s.push(head);
            break;
        } else {
            int precedence2;
            if (head == '+' || head == '-')
                precedence2 = 1;
            else
                precedence2 = 2;
            // if the precedence of the new operator
            // is less than the precedence of the old operator
            if (precedence2 < precedence1) {
                s.push(head); // push operator to stack
                break;
            }
            // if precedence not less, print to output
            else
                out = out + head;
        }
    }
    s.push(oper);
}

/**
 * if parentheses is open paren, ignore else print to output
 * 
 * @param c
 * @throws PostFixException
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public void parentheses(char c) throws PostFixException, IOException {      
    if(s.isEmpty()) out = "Invalid";

    while (!s.isEmpty()) {
        char a = (char) s.pop();
//      if(((Stack) s.peek()).isEmpty()){}
        if (a == '(')
            break;
        else
            out = out + a;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty lost about this!

**edit**
I've tried running the input through an algorithm that will put it into the proper format (which is number space operator space number etc etc) which definitely solves a lot of the issue, but I think the major part of the issue would be easier to discover using the stacks.

For example, in the last method, parentheses, I tried adding:

```
    if(s.isEmpty()) out = "Invalid";
```

however for some reason it doesn't work, the output never prints if that if statement occurs and instead I just get an error and the program stops running, I'm not sure why.

Comment: Please avoid unnecessary whitespace when putting code in your question - this will make your question much more readable

Comment: ok i'll edit it sorry!

Comment: Also, when asking question, please tell us what you have tried so far and not just "I'm lost" or "it does not work". Show that you put some effort into this.
In your case, have you tried validating the syntax of your input with a regular expression, so when you do the parsing (which is your code) you can assume a well-formed formula?

Comment: @SirRichie I had some attempts within the code but I added a clarification for one of the things I tried in an edit

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger, stepping through your code and compare the expected controlflow vs. what is actually happening?